# Matlab/Simulink: How to programmatically edit the Solar Cell component?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to programmatically add components to a Simulink model. The programmatic model editing logic of MATLAB is very straight-forward ([reference](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/simulink/programmatic-modeling.html)), but here I run into an issue.

I am struggling with the thermal port of the Solar Cell component (located at `elec_lib/Sources/Solar Cell`).

The visual result is shown in the images below: in the first image the initially added component (programmatically added), in the second image the same component, with the thermal port (orange) exposed. This can be done manually, by right-clicking on the component, navigating to `Simscape > Block choices > Show Thermal Port`. But how can this be done programmatically?

[image: Solar Cell without Thermal Port]

[image: Solar Cell with Thermal Port]

So far, I investigated the `ObjectParameters` of the component with the command:

```
get_param(model,'ObjectParameters')
```

I found out that the parameter `ComponentPath` changes when I do the thermal port exposure manually (from `elec.sources.solar_cell` to `elec.sources.solar_cell_thermal`). There are further parameters which are changing, but they are all read-only when I try to manipulate them myself programmatically.
Consequently, I tried to change `ComponentPath` with

```
set_param(model,'ComponentPath','elec.sources.solar_cell_thermal')
```

which works, but doesn't influence the visual appearance of the component at all.

Would appreciate any help or comment – I really depend on it! Standing in front of a wall here...

Comment: I don’t see any difference  between your images.

Comment: I am sorry Scott, thanks for pointing it out. I updated the images.